# Spark cassandra connector in Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I need to connect my standalone Spark to my Cassandra instance in python. I have downloaded Apache spark from the  [Apache website](http://spark.apache.org/), extracted and built it as such:

```
tar -xvf spark-1.4.1.tgz
sbt/sbt assembly
```

I added updated the ./bashrc file and i can run Spark. I also have Cassandra  set up where i can pull data from my python program.

How do i connect Spark to the Cassandra instance to access Cassandra tables as Spark RDDs ?

Answer (score 1):

A DataFrame compatible interface is available through the Spark Cassandra Connector
https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md

An RDD interface based on wrapping the Connector is available as well
https://github.com/TargetHolding/pyspark-cassandra

In both cases you will end up adding the package/lib to your application via

```
--packages or --jars
```

and specifying your Cassandra connection host

```
--conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=yourhost
```

### Dataframes (Requires the Spark Cassandra Connector)

```
 sqlContext.read\
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .options(table="kv", keyspace="test")\
    .load().show()
```

### RDDs (Requires Pyspark-Cassandra)

```
sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "table")
```